# `unrecognized selector` error when setting delegate to UISearchBar's textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar, unrecognized-selector

I am using iOS8.0 and I want to set UITextFieldDelegate to UITextField inside UISearchBar control.
I already get the text field inside search bar successfully and I can set a custom text to it also.
But when I set UITextFieldDelegate to that TextField, the app crash whenever I touch inside the search bar.

Please help to take a look and tell me if I make any mistake. Thanks.
Here is crash Log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginToSafraViewController
>   _searchController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b469440'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00962746 **exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x005eba97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0096a705 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x008b1287 ___forwarding_** + 1047
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x008b0e4e
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14    5   UIKit                               0x012b0e2b -[UISearchBarTextField canBecomeFirstResponder] + 96     6
>   UIKit                               0x010fabac -[UIResponder(Internal)
>   _canBecomeFirstResponder] + 33    7   UIKit                               0x010f923a -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 240    8   UIKit
>   0x00fb8348 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114    9   UIKit 
>   0x017763e7 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51   10  UIKit
>   0x0137f7f8
>   -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 200     11  UIKit
>   0x01381e26
>   -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2762   12  UIKit
>   0x01375677 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 327  13  UIKit
>   0x01373ef4 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:]
>   + 561     14  UIKit                               0x01375f3d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60    15  UIKit                               0x013798ba ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 57    16 
>   UIKit                               0x0137977d

Code to find the text field:

```
UITextField *searchTextField = [self findTextFieldInsideSearchBar:x];
if (searchTextField != nil)
{
    [arr addObject:searchTextField];
    [searchTextField setText:@"sfsfsdf"];
    [searchTextField setDelegate:self];
}


-(UITextField*) findTextFieldInsideSearchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar
{
    for (UIView* view in searchBar.subviews) {
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue >= 7){
            //at iOS v7.0 and later,
            for (UIView* subSubView in view.subviews) {
                if([subSubView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])

                    return (UITextField*) subSubView;
            }
        }else{
            //iOS v6.0 and erlier.
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                return (UITextField*) view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Your mistake is digging into the private inner workings of `UISearchBar` and changing the private text field's `delegate` to something it wasn't expecting. Why are you trying to change the text field's `delegate` property?

Comment: seems like you are assigning UITextFieldDelegate to UITextField, have you declare your UITextField implemented UITextFieldDelegate protocol?

Comment: Ah! yes! I my VC, there are many UITextField controls as well as UISearchBar control. I want to push the view up whenever keyboard show and hide focusing textfield. Sothat, I implement the UITextFieldDelegate and change frame of Self.View when needed . It works fine with UITextField, but crash with UISearchBar.

Comment: Listen for the keyboard notifications instead of using the text field delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy: I need to handle keyboard notification as well as textField Delegate also (Based on feature requirement). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What delegate method do you need for the search bar's text field? Can't you use the appropriate `UISearchBarDelegate` methods?

Comment: I want to implement some actions inside '- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditting: (NSNotification*)notification'.  I also try to implement appropriate method of UISearchBarDelegate but it still crash.

Comment: It's crashing because you can't change the delegate of the search field's text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set delegate of this textfield directly;

You should inherit your searchBar and set the textfield delegate like this;

```
MySearchBar* mySearchBar = [[MySearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
mySearchBar.textFieldDelegate = self; // TO BE NOTED. SETTING textFieldDelegate. SAME WOULD WORK FOR XIB OR STORYBOARD
[self.view addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

========================

```
//  MySearchBar.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MySearchBar : UISearchBar

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UITextFieldDelegate> textFieldDelegate;

@end
```

===============

```
//  MySearchBar.m

#import "MySearchBar.h"

@implementation MySearchBar

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldBeginEditing:)])
    {
        return  [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldShouldBeginEditing:textField];;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} //F.E.

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)])
    {
        [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];;
    }
}//F.E.

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldEndEditing:)])
    {
        return  [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldShouldEndEditing:textField];;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} //F.E.

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:)])
    {
        [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldDidEndEditing:textField];;
    }
} //F.E.

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)])
    {
        return  [self.textFieldDelegate textField:textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:string];;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} //F.E.

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldClear:)])
    {
        return  [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldShouldClear:textField];;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} //F.E.

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (self.textFieldDelegate && [self.textFieldDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)])
    {
        return  [self.textFieldDelegate textFieldShouldReturn:textField];;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
} //F.E.

@end
```